# Clustered Index - Query Performing Index Scan

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning

Why does the below query perform an Index Scan rather than an Index Seek?

I would have thought the Index would act as a covering index?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CustomerFileDate] 
ON [dbo].[UserData] 
(
    [CustomerID] ASC,
    [FileDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([UserID],[User])

-- query
SELECT c.User, c.UserID 
FROM ClientData c
WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID
AND FileDate >= @StartDate
AND FileDate <= @EndDate
```

Execution Plan posted to [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c0z75immiku85li/Execution%20plan.xml)

Thanks!

Comment: Your first two sentences are very different questions.  Are you wondering why this is a Scan vs. Seek?  Or are you wondering why your index (IX_CustomerFileDate) wasn't chosen over another index?

Comment: It **is** a covering index, but that doesn't mean that it should do a seek instead of a scan

Comment: Without seeing the actual execution plan, we could only guess. Guesses don't make for good answers. Could you post the actual (not estimated) plan somewhere, please?

Comment: Hi, execution plan added.

Comment: There is a **huge** difference between the estimated rows and the actual rows. Have you updated the statistics of that table recently?, doing that should make the optimizer choose a better plan for your query

Comment: Statistics were updated on the Index this morning.

Comment: You should update statistics on the table

Answer (score 7):

The Execution plan shows a non clustered index scan:

[image]

Because you have a implicit conversion of your first index seek column SQL Server decided to do a full non clustered index scan. It's not doing a clustered index scan because the non clustered index is a covering index. 1)

[image]

You can see that the column customerID needs to be converted to a NVARCHAR(50) datatype.(red conversion). Because the column first needs to be converted, it can't be used. Since it's the first column in your index, it effectively makes the index useless for seeks or estimates.

Why is SQL Server doing a implicit conversion of the column? Because on the right side of the = sign you feed it a Nvarchar. Your not doing this explicit, since also the parameter @CustomerID first gets implictly converted to a NVARCHAR(3) (blue conversion).

I presume this is because your are filling @CustomerID with a Unicode value. However, It would suprise me that you would use a unicode values and yet have non unicode datatypes defined in your table. Maybe somebody else could confirm the reason for the blue conversion.

1) *I deleted a wrong assumtion about the relevance of the amount of rows returned that [Martin Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith) was nice enough to point out to me.*

Comment: Regarding the blue conversion I think this is because the collation of the variable is different from the collation of the column. If I create a database with default collation `COLLATE SQL_Ukrainian_CP1251_CI_AS` and query a column of datatype `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` I see that for example.

Comment: Hi @Edward, I updated `@CustomerID` to match the table data type - varchar(50). It now uses an Index Seek, but is still doing conversions... `Seek Keys[1]: Prefix: [TestData].[dbo].[UserData].CustomerID = Scalar Operator(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(50),[@CustomerID],0)), 
Start: [TestData].[dbo].[UserData].FileDate >= Scalar Operator([@StartDate]), 
End: [TestData].[dbo].[UserData].FileDate <= Scalar Operator([@EndDate])`........ Also Estimated Number of Rows is still huge compared to Actual Number of Rows.

Comment: @k09 - Conversions of the **parameters** aren't such a problem. Presumably that is the collation issue. And you will almost certainly get the same plan anyway even if estimated vs actual is accurate.  Did you update the statistics on the table though? Also in the XML version of the plan what are `ParameterRuntimeValue` and `ParameterCompileValue`?

Comment: @k09 - Actually looking at your previous plan the values aren't sniffed at all. Are you using variables rather than parameters? You can add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to get accurate cardinality estimates but the plan will probably still end up the same.

Comment: @Martin. Statistics updated on this specific Index. Is this enough? By Parameter do you mean using question mark? Using variables e.g. `declare @StartDate datetime = '2014/01/03'`

Comment: @k09 - Yes that is a variable. The values of variables are never sniffed and the estimated rows shown are just guesses based on the average density of `CustomerID` and the nature of the predicates on `FileDate`. If you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of the query you should see the discrepancy reduced. To parameterise adhoc SQL in TSQL you would need to use `sp_executesql`